# (Intel core i5-760) MOVQ QWORD PTR DS:[Address],XMM0

Tags: c++, assembly

Recently I got a problem with my program (on another computer), it crashed on a startup, so I managed to debug it on a remote computer and on mine. And I found out an interesting thing, following code on my computer:

```
010F131D    660FD605 681110 MOVQ QWORD PTR DS:[1101168],XMM0
010F1325    660FD605 701110 MOVQ QWORD PTR DS:[1101170],XMM0
```

Is not represented on a remote computer:

```
0012131C     50             PUSH EAX
0012131D     66             DB 66
0012131E     0F             DB 0F
0012131F     D6             DB D6
00121320     05             DB 05
00121321     68111300       DD 1101168
00121325     66             DB 66
00121326     0F             DB 0F
00121327     D6             SALC
00121328     05 70111300    ADD EAX,1101170
010F131C     50             PUSH EAX
```

Stepping into 'DB 66' the program crashes..

Both of computers have 64x version of windows (my: win8_64x; remote: win7_64x)
Processors: (my: intel core i7-2600; remote: intel core i5-760) 
C++ Program was compiled on my computer (while I had win7_64x) with VC++2012 using toolkit v110_xp  and /O2 /Ot flags..

My question is: what is the source of the problem and how can it be solved?
(should I post some more information?)

Comment: How are you obtaining these disassembly dumps?  Are both taken from the same debugger, one running locally and one connected remotely, or are they from different debuggers, one running on each machine?

Also, based on your statement about compilation:  the program running on the remote computer is just a binary copy of the local version, right?  It's not a separate build?

Comment: Are the compiler and linker options the same between the two builds?

Comment: Yes, the program on a remote computer is a copy of program that is on local computer. These builds are the same.

Debuggers are the same -- OllyDbg110

Comment: My fault, debuggers are different: OllyDbg201(my, local) and OllyDbg110 (remote). That's why this code cannot be passed..

Comment: Sorry for this mistake. I think this question can be closed.. I'll continue research on a remote computer with newer version of OllyDbg. (but the program hangs on that call which contains the code above)